# Regex single character user name validation

Tags: java, regex

Regular expression mentioned below is used to validate a user input in Java.

```
username.matches("^\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\p{Z}.']+")
```

The regular expression is working for more than one character input, but fails for single character input.

As '+' denotes one and more than one characters, I confused how to support one character input as valid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have will match 2 or more symbols. The reason is, this is symbol one (or more):

```
\\p{L}+
```

And this is symbol 2 (or more):

```
[\\p{L}\\p{Z}.']+
```

Most likely you want the last part to be "0 or more", like this:

```
"^\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\p{Z}.']*"
```

Comment: My bad! I missed the second '+' sign

Answer (score 2):

That's because both parts in your regex are requiring at least one character each (see the `+` almost at the end of the regex).  If you want that part to be optional, it should be `*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex requires a minimum of 2 characters.

"^\p{L}+" - minimum of 1
"[\p{L}\p{Z}.']+" - minimum of 1

The "+" does denote one or more characters.